issue with unit-testing spark scala project related to json4s
I'm using scala 2.12, spark 3.1.2, and jdk 1.8, and I'm facing what looks to be a dependency issue: A needed class was not found. This could be due to an error in your runpath. Missing class: org/json4s/JsonAST$JValue.
$scalaMajorVersion:$sparkVersion" mentioned below map to these version numbers.
I have created a reusable testing fixture, that I would like to use across various submodules in my scala project to unit-test spark specific logic.
My project is broken down as such:
├───module_a
     build.gradle
│    src/
      main/
       scala/
        SparkTransformationLogic.scala
      tests/
        TestSparkTransformationLogic.scala
├───common-test-utils
    build.gradle
│   src/
     main/
      scala/
       SparkTestingFixture.scala
├───module_c
    build.gradle
     main/
       scala/
        FooBarLogic.scala
      tests/
        TestFooBarLogic.scala
build.gradle

I want to reuse the SparkTestingFixture that I've created in the common-test-utils module. If possible, the tests should use isolated dependencies locally, but I think I'm running into solving this point, and debugging the json4s error mentioned above.
Module A build.gradle:
apply plugin: 'com.company.gradle.foobar.library'

dependencies {
    implementation project(":common-test-utils")

    implementation("org.apache.spark:spark-core_$scalaMajorVersion:$sparkVersion"){
        exclude group: "org.apache.logging.log4j"
    }
    implementation "org.apache.spark:spark-mllib_$scalaMajorVersion:$sparkVersion"
    implementation ("org.apache.spark:spark-sql_$scalaMajorVersion:$sparkVersion"){
        exclude group: "org.apache.logging.log4j"
    }
    implementation "org.apache.spark:spark-streaming_$scalaMajorVersion:$sparkVersion"
    implementation "org.apache.spark:spark-hive_$scalaMajorVersion:$sparkVersion"

    implementation "com.company.yahoobug:jvm-config-api:$jvmConfigVersion"
    implementation "com.company.yahoobug:sparkutils-environment:$sparkUtilsVersion"
    implementation "com.company.yahoobug:sparkutils-job:$sparkUtilsVersion"
    implementation "com.company.yahoobug:sparkutils-logging:$sparkUtilsVersion"
    implementation "com.company.yahoobug:sparkutils-spark:$sparkUtilsVersion"

    testImplementation "org.scalatest:scalatest_$scalaMajorVersion:$scalaTestVersion"
    testImplementation "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.36"
    testImplementation "org.json4s:json4s-jackson_2.12:3.6.7"
}

Module common-test-utils build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'scala'
}

apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "scala"

dependencies {
    implementation("org.apache.spark:spark-core_$scalaMajorVersion:$sparkVersion")
    implementation "org.apache.spark:spark-mllib_$scalaMajorVersion:$sparkVersion"
    implementation("org.apache.spark:spark-sql_$scalaMajorVersion:$sparkVersion")
    implementation "org.apache.spark:spark-streaming_$scalaMajorVersion:$sparkVersion"
    implementation "org.apache.spark:spark-hive_$scalaMajorVersion:$sparkVersion"
    implementation "org.scalatest:scalatest_$scalaMajorVersion:$scalaTestVersion"

    implementation "org.json4s:json4s-core_2.12:3.6.7"
    implementation "org.json4s:json4s-native_2.12:3.6.7"
    implementation "org.json4s:json4s-jackson_2.12:3.6.7"
}

Root project build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'com.foobar.gradle.repos' version '0.3.10'
    id 'com.foobar.gradle.foozy.library' version "1.0.23"
    id 'com.github.maiflai.scalatest' version '0.35'
    id 'com.foobar.gradle.checks' version '1.2.3'
}

apply from: 'versions.gradle'

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "com.github.maiflai.scalatest"
    group 'com.foobar.foozy'
}

subprojects {

    apply plugin: 'java-library'
    apply plugin: 'scala'
    apply plugin: "com.foorbar.gradle.repos"
    apply plugin: "com.github.maiflai.scalatest"

    fooBarRepositoryPlugin {
        forceGuavaVersion = false
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
        targetCompatibility = "1.8"
    }

    configurations {
        sparkTestImplementation
        sparkTestRuntimeOnly
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation "org.scala-lang:scala-library:$scalaVersion"
        implementation "org.scala-lang.modules:scala-java8-compat_$scalaMajorVersion:0.9.1"
        implementation "org.openjdk.jol:jol-core:0.9" // for local object size diagnostics
        implementation "commons-io:commons-io:2.4"

        implementation "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:$hadoopVersion"
        implementation "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-core:$hadoopVersion"
        implementation("org.apache.spark:spark-core_$scalaMajorVersion:$sparkVersion") {
            exclude group: "org.apache.logging.log4j"
        }
        implementation "org.apache.spark:spark-mllib_$scalaMajorVersion:$sparkVersion"
        implementation "org.apache.spark:spark-sql_$scalaMajorVersion:$sparkVersion"
        implementation "org.apache.spark:spark-streaming_$scalaMajorVersion:$sparkVersion"
        implementation "org.apache.spark:spark-hive_$scalaMajorVersion:$sparkVersion"

        implementation "org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:1.1.2.1"
        implementation "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:1.11.333"
        implementation "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ec2:1.11.333"
        implementation "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kinesis:1.11.333"

        implementation "joda-time:joda-time:$jodaVersion"
        implementation "com.github.nscala-time:nscala-time_$scalaMajorVersion:2.14.0"

        compile "com.datadoghq:java-dogstatsd-client:$dogstatsdVersion"

        testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12"
        testImplementation "org.scalatestplus:scalatestplus-junit_$scalaMajorVersion:1.0.0-M2"
        testImplementation "org.scalatest:scalatest_$scalaMajorVersion:$scalaTestVersion"
        testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-all:$mockitoVersion"
        implementation "com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-all:0.62.2" 
        
        testRuntimeOnly "org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:1.7.30"
        testImplementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-1.2-api:2.17.2'

    }

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:5.0.0'
        }
    }

}

checks {
    checkScalaStyle = false
}

// Script to copy audit test data
task zipTipZap {
    description "Publish task"

    doLast {

        println("gathering audit data for $project.name")

        copy { //Test Results
            from ('.') {
                include '**/test-results/**/TEST-*.xml'
                exclude '**/build/audit_data' //exclude itself from scanning
            }
            into 'build/audit_data/test_results'
            includeEmptyDirs false
        }
    }
}

Spark Testing Fixture:

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
//import org.scalatest.funsuite.AnyFunSuite
import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfterEach, Suite}

import java.io.File
import java.nio.file.Files


trait SparkSessionFixture extends BeforeAndAfterEach { this: Suite =>
  @transient var spark: SparkSession = _

  val warehouseLocation: String = Files.createTempDirectory("spark-warehouse").toFile.getAbsolutePath
  val metastoreLocation: String = Files.createTempDirectory("spark-metastore").toFile.getAbsolutePath
  val tempHadoopDir: File = Files.createTempDirectory("hadoop_home").toFile

  System.setProperty("derby.system.home", metastoreLocation)
  System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", tempHadoopDir.getAbsolutePath)

  override protected def beforeEach(): Unit = {
    super.beforeEach()
    spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master("local")
      .appName("spark session")
      .config("spark.ui.enabled", "false")
      .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "1")
      .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
      .config("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL", s"jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true")
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()

  }

  override protected def afterEach(): Unit = {
    if (spark != null) {
      spark.stop()
    }
    super.afterEach()
  }

}

If anyone has suggestions as to what is causing the dependency collision with json4s or how to keep spark testing isolated with its own set of dependencies to avoid the json4s error, I would appreciate some guidance!

    implementation "org.json4s:json4s-core_2.12:3.6.7"
    implementation "org.json4s:json4s-native_2.12:3.6.7"
    implementation "org.json4s:json4s-jackson_2.12:3.6.7"

Per your other question you should not need this, the correct version will be included from your spark-sql dependency.  Don't add dependencies if you can avoid it, the runtime needs matching versions and the Spark project tests only against those versions.
Sql depends on core which depends on json4s-jackson 3.7.0-M5.  3.6 isn't compatible so you get the error (there may be other reasons but that's a prime one).  In gradle you can use the dependencies task to help with this:
gradle -q dependencies

insights can be used to show exactly how that dependency is used.
Moreover 'implementation' probably shouldn't be used for any spark stuff (Maven has provided scope for exactly this use case).  If you intend to run it on a spark server then spark is already provided and you should not depend on a specific runtime (rather than the api), this build.gradle is a working shaded build per this question
Your build files are full of very specific library usages that should all be transitive from spark - try using insights to see what is going on but per this link you should probably just try again with your dependencies starting with just spark.

Even without adding these, I get the conflict. And i can see multiple versioning still on json4s in the classpath

./gradlew dependencies yields nothing related to json4s
